# Question var_dump output { ["inicio"]=> &int(6) }

Tags: php

I initialize `$this->Pag` in the construcot of class

```
$this->Pag = ["inicio" => 1, "fin" => 24];
```

`$this->Pag["fin"]` was a MySql query SELECT COUNT

My problem is when I execute this code and I mock the result and the gretter than in if go wrong. And I don't Know why go this check wrong and `var_dump` print &int how type of `$this->Pag["inicio"]`

```php
$this->Pag["inicio"] = 6;
        echo "inicio: " . $this->Pag["inicio"] . PHP_EOL;
        echo "fin: " . $this->Pag["fin"] . PHP_EOL;
        var_dump($this->Pag["inicio"] >= $this->Pag["Fin"]);
        echo PHP_EOL;
        var_dump($this->Pag);
```

output:

```
string(1) "5"
inicio: 6
fin: 24
bool(true)

array(2) {
  ["inicio"]=>
  &int(6)
  ["fin"]=>
  int(24)
}
```

The problem is when I check 6>=24 return true;

Comment: Instead of `var_dump(intval($this->Pag["inicio"]) >= $this->Pag["Fin"]);` you should use `var_dump(intval($this->Pag["inicio"]) >= $this->Pag["fin"]);` (with lower case fin)

Comment: I use $this->Pag because this is part of class

Comment: My point was about "fin" vs "Fin"

Comment: Ahh ok thanks this was the problem